# R plot text: How to add regular text prefix to polynomial rendered in exponent form (not ^)

Tags: r, parsing, plot, text, expression

I'm trying to add this text to a plot: "Model:  y = 1 + 2x - 3x^2 + 4x^3"
where actual exponents are rendered as such (no ^ chars).  (See screenshot)

Below is repro code.  The first text() call works fine (no prepended regular text), but the second does not (with prepended text).  (Execute soTest() to repro.)

Any suggestions?  I guess I don't know which R keywords to search for to find a solution.  Any help would be appreciated!  (Please pardon the camel-casing, I'm writing a slide deck for an audience with at least a few non-R coders.)

```
evalPoly <- function( x, coeff ) {
    if ( length( coeff ) < 1 ) return( c(0) )   
    termSum <- 0
    for ( i in 1:length(coeff) ) {
        termSum <- termSum + coeff[i] * x^(i-1)
    }
    return( termSum )
}

soTest <- function() {
    coeff <- c( 1, 2, -3, 4 )
    x <- 1:8
    y <- evalPoly( x, coeff )
    plot( x, y )
    text( 2, 1600, parse( text="1+2*x-3*x^2+4*x^3" ), adj=0 )
    text( 2, 1400, parse( text="Model:  y = 1+2*x-3*x^2+4*x^3" ), adj=0 )
}
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Apparently an '=' sign needs to be escaped like so: '=='.
Here is a new soTest() function as well as the resulting screenshot.  It works.
Thanks to those who spent time on this question.

```
soTest2 <- function() {
    coeff <- c( 1, 2, -3, 4 )
    x <- 1:8
    y <- evalPoly( x, coeff )
    plot( x, y )
    text( 2, 1600, parse( text="1+2*x-3*x^2+4*x^3" ), adj=0 )
    text( 2, 1400, parse( text="Model:  y == 1+2*x-3*x^2+4*x^3" ), adj=0 )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Caveat: I don't know R well, so am learning a lot.  I have since learned that I am using parse() in a way it wasn't intended ([general text] + [expression]).  The above does work, but you cannot extend it to arbitrary text prefixes (I don't think).  Fyi.  Thanks, Rick  PS: I have had some success adding > 1 prefix word by embedding them in apostrophes.  I am sure a more knowledgeable R person could provide a more correct approach.

Comment: Here is a link showing how I ended up annotating plots with LaTeX like math:  https://sites.google.com/site/rickcreamer/Home/r/leastsquaresintrotoml/plot6

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull the plain text outside the parse statement.

```
text( 2, 1400, paste("Model:  y =", parse( text="1+2*x-3*x^2+4*x^3" )), adj=0 )
```

Comment: Thanks but I then lose the nice exponent visualization - it reverts back to using literal '^' characters.